# col-md-6 ocupando todo o espaço

Tags: css, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

No meu formulário de contato preciso deixar de um lado algumas informações sobre o contato, e do outro lado um formulário com e-mail e mensagem. Porém a parte do meu form das informações esta ocupando tudo, e quando eu tento adicionar o input de email ele cai pra baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Na parte laranja era para ficar o input email.

```css
.col-md-12 {
  background-color: red;
}

.col-md-6 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="contato-content display-table">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <h1>Fale conosco</h1>
        <div class="linha-separador mt-2"></div>
        <p class="mt-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia cupiditate aliquid molestiae non obcaecati</p>
        <div class="contato-itens">
          <div class="circulo-itens mr-5"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
            <p class="mt-5">xxxx</p>
          </div>
          <div class="circulo-itens  mr-5"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
            <p class="mt-5">xxxx</p>
          </div>
          <div class="circulo-itens  mr-5"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
            <p class="mt-5">xxxx</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form>
          <input class="form-control form-control" type="text" placeholder="EMAIL">
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Altere `<div class="col-md-12">` para `<div class="row">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao invés de colocar as duas colunas `col-md-6` dentro de uma coluna `col-md-12`, por que não coloca dentro de uma `row`? A linha ocupa as 12 colunas e não possui os espaçamentos que uma coluna possui, que quebra o seu layout.

```css
.col-md-12 {
  background-color: red;
}

.col-md-6 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="contato-content display-table">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <h1>Fale conosco</h1>
        <div class="linha-separador mt-2"></div>
        <p class="mt-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia cupiditate aliquid molestiae non obcaecati</p>
        <div class="contato-itens">
          <div class="circulo-itens mr-5"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
            <p class="mt-5">xxxx</p>
          </div>
          <div class="circulo-itens  mr-5"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
            <p class="mt-5">xxxx</p>
          </div>
          <div class="circulo-itens  mr-5"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
            <p class="mt-5">xxxx</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form>
          <input class="form-control form-control" type="text" placeholder="EMAIL">
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Assim funciona, o problema que não fica responsivo, quando diminui a resolução ele cai pra cima do footer.

Answer (score 0):

O `Bootstrap` em versão **3.x** isso funcionava, porém na versão atual **4.x** aparentemente o `.col-*` requer um pai `.row`, acredito que isso deve ser por causa do esquema de `flex-box`.

Obs. No código abaixo eu troquei `.col-md-*` por `.col-*` isso para que ele obedeça o tamanho em telas menores. Se eu não estou enganado só definindo o tamanho `md` telas menores utilizaram o equivalente a `.col-12`

```css
.col-12 {
  background-color: red;
}

.col-6 {
  border:blue solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="contato-content display-table">
    <div class="container">
        <div class='row'> <!-- adicionado -->
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class='row'> <!-- adicionado -->
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <h1>Fale conosco</h1>
                        <div class="linha-separador mt-2"></div>
                        <p class="mt-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia cupiditate aliquid molestiae non obcaecati</p>
                        <div class="contato-itens">
                            <div class="circulo-itens mr-5">
                                <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
                                <p class="mt-5">xxxx</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="circulo-itens  mr-5">
                                <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                                <p class="mt-5">xxxx</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="circulo-itens  mr-5">
                                <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                                <p class="mt-5">xxxx</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <form>
                            <input class="form-control form-control" type="text" placeholder="EMAIL">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- fim row interna -->
            </div> <!-- fim col-12 -->
        </div> <!-- fim da row externa -->
    </div> <!-- fim do container -->
</div> <!-- fim contato-content -->
```